# How to get position value from a model (catalog/product_image) in Magento?

Tags: image, magento

I only have this Magento model (catalog/product_image). Is there any way for me to get position value or label value of that image. When I var dump this model, I can only get width, height, quality, _keepAspectRatio, etc. The most valuable data I can get from it is image file name like this: /s/e/productABC.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not quite sure if you will get anything more useful from the catalog/product_image model. From your question it sounds like you are wanting to fetch the image label. If you have access to a product object you can use:

```
$_product->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemByColumnValue('label', 'LABEL_NAME')->getUrl();
```

This will return you the label of the image.

If you need any more help please share what objects you have access to and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sweet. That's what I'm looking for. However, since I only have image file name and want to retrieve that label or position value from a varien objec, the code I will use is:    $this->getProduct()->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemByColumnValue('file', $this->getImageFile());

Answer (score 0):

in that class there is just one property and one set and one get function for file

Property : `protected $_baseFile;`

Function

```
/**
     * Set filenames for base file and new file
     *
     * @param string $file
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image
     */
    public function setBaseFile($file)
```

and

```
public function getBaseFile()
    {
        return $this->_baseFile;
    }
```

This implies: You will not get position using this object.
Just check `getBaseFile` that will return a string.

I always suggest that for any given object if extended from `varien_object` use `$object->debug();` as this provides lot of information on what all it stores.